# Sending SOAP request to UDP broadcast address

Tags: java, soap

I need to send SOAP request to UDP broadcast address.
Here is the code I use:

```
    URL endpoint = new URL("udp://239.255.255.250:3702");
    SOAPConnection connection = sfc.createConnection();
    SOAPMessage responseMessage = connection.call(requestMessage, endpoint);
```

But the problem is I cant create URL object with "udp://239.255.255.250:3702" as argument. Here is error:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: udp
```

Any idea what to do?

Comment: UDP: isn't an implemented URL protocol. You're just making this up. It doesn't begin to make sense. If you send a request to a broadcast address you are going to get multiple responses. Which one are you going to accept?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The normal usage of SOAP is over HTTP. If you want to use the SOAP-over-UDP standard, your best tactic would be to find an existing library that implements it (StackOverflow is not the place to look for one, though), otherwise you'll have to implement it yourself. But is that really your aim or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: I am trying to do web service discovery and to send Probe message to which all clients should answer... I tried java-ws-discovery, but it is not working for web service I user.